# Alternatives to the "byvar" function in the metamean model "Meta-analysis of single means"

Tags: categorical-data, mean, meta-analysis, reliability-meta-analysis

I have collected data from 300+ studies on microplastic densities in rivers, I would like to investigate how they vary with numeric variables (population density, Average GDP, plastic production) and character variables (vegetated/non-vegetated, continent, ecoregion, climatic zone).

However, when running "metamean", and using the "byvar" function I can only analyze one variable at a time. Can anyone recommend a mutivariate method so I can look at what factors are driving the microplastic variation?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you mean the function metamean from the package mean then have you thought of trying metagen?

Comment: Hi, Yes I am using the "metamean" function in the "meta" package.  I had a look at "metagen" but it has the same problem for me in that it can only handle one variable at a time. This means I have sequential analysis using one factor at a time, first "population density" then " ecoregion" etc. to see whether they are driving differences in the microplastic density. As this analysis method is not very efficient at detecting differences I was hoping for an alternative. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Try metareg then

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.